# preg_split with last 2-3 characters non alphanumerical

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

So I'm working on some php, and looking for some help with regular exp.

I have an array of string looking like this:

```
$variable_with_strings
array(
    [0][art] => >AngusDelu -
    [1][art] => >PatatasJr -
    [2][art] => >AngusHabane *
    [3][art] => >Papas Med *
    [4][art] => >AngusDelu*
    [5][art] => >Papas Med*
    [6][art] => >AngusHabane**
    [7][art] => >Papas Med**
    [8][art] => >Papas Med_*-
    [9][art] => >Manza Med_*-
)
```

**I loop tru each one, treating as single variable ($variable_with_strings**

And I want to split the string in two for later group it

something looking for a regex with `preg_split()` like this:
(I need the two parts; 1.-the description item and 2.- the group signs)

for each one I expect to have:

```
$word = array
    [art] => >AngusDelu
    [sep] =>  -)

$word = array(
    [art] => >PatatasJr
    [sep] =>  -)

$word = array(
    [art] => >AngusHabane
    [sep] =>  *)

$word = array(
    [art] => >Papas Med
    [sep] =>  *)

$word = array(
    [art] => >AngusDelu
    [sep] => *)

$word = array(
    [art] => >Papas Med
    [sep] => *)

$word = array(
    [art] => >AngusHabane
    [sep] => **)

$word = array(    
    [art] => >Papas Med
    [sep] => **)

$word = array(
    [art] => >Papas Med
    [sep] => _*-)

$word = array(
    [art] => >Manza Med
    [sep] => _*-)
)
```

So I was using something like:

```
$word = preg_split('/[^\w]/',$variable_with_strings);
```

But this splits every white space,

This is kinda tricky, I guess, because in the first character there is a `>` always, and the last characters are `*`, `_`, `-` or some time a space before these " ", and some times the special chars come in 1, 2 or even 3 at the end.

can this be done this way?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use preg_split, match just the end of the string like `/(\W+$)/` and also pass the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flags as the fourth parameter to capture whatever you are splitting on as part of the result. `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` captures the delimeter you are splitting on and `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` will make sure there are no empty results.

Example:

```
<?php
$art = array(
    '>AngusDelu -',
    '>PatatasJr -',
    '>AngusHabane *',
    '>Papas Med *',
    '>AngusDelu*',
    '>Papas Med*',
    '>AngusHabane**',
    '>Papas Med**',
    '>Papas Med--',
    '>Manza Med--',
    );

foreach($art as $a){
    $split = preg_split('/(\W+$)/', $a, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    echo '<pre>'.print_r($split,true).'</pre>';
}
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/9mCDlc

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => >AngusDelu
    [1] =>  -
)

Array
(
    [0] => >PatatasJr
    [1] =>  -
)

Array
(
    [0] => >AngusHabane
    [1] =>  *
)

Array
(
    [0] => >Papas Med
    [1] =>  *
)

Array
(
    [0] => >AngusDelu
    [1] => *
)

Array
(
    [0] => >Papas Med
    [1] => *
)

Array
(
    [0] => >AngusHabane
    [1] => **
)

Array
(
    [0] => >Papas Med
    [1] => **
)

Array
(
    [0] => >Papas Med
    [1] => --
)

Array
(
    [0] => >Manza Med
    [1] => --
)
```

Each one is in a separate array because you said that you have an array, so you need to loop over and run split on each entry in the array. You could easily work with one array at a time in the loop or combine them into a single array to work with later.

Comment: In fact each one of the orginal is a $var not the whole a single one

Comment: Well, then this would work fine on an individual `$var`. That is essentially what the example does.

Comment: this worked fine on individuals $vars, using "0" modificator instead of "-1" since I needed all of the last characters delimited in another $var, thanks, sorry for the poor redaction/slow answer, @chris85

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. In all cases given, the above would appear to work without issue. And the only place I'm using `-1` is in the limit argument which just means "no limit". The manual specifically states that `A limit of -1, 0 or NULL means "no limit"`, so changing that to `0` would make no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use

```
[^a-z]+$
```

with `preg_replace` and the `m` and `i` modifiers. (Your examples don't have numbers; if you want numbers as well add `\d` in the character class)

Regex101 demo: https://regex101.com/r/rX3oK7/2 (note the `g` modifier on the demo isn't used in PHP, the `preg_replace` is global already)

PHP Usage:

```
$string = '[art] => >AngusDelu -
[art] => >PatatasJr -
[art] => >AngusHabane *
[art] => >Papas Med *
[art] => >AngusDelu*
[art] => >Papas Med*
[art] => >AngusHabane**
[art] => >Papas Med**
[art] => >Papas Med--
[art] => >Manza Med--';
echo preg_replace('/[^a-z]+$/im', '', $string);
```

Output:

```
[art] => >AngusDelu
[art] => >PatatasJr
[art] => >AngusHabane
[art] => >Papas Med
[art] => >AngusDelu
[art] => >Papas Med
[art] => >AngusHabane
[art] => >Papas Med
[art] => >Papas Med
[art] => >Manza Med
```

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/479444

Comment: Is this eliminating the last characters? cause I need those for later grouping- association

Comment: Oh, I see you want to take out the other characters and move them to the next line, is that right? Maybe like this? https://eval.in/479454

Comment: thats it! Im updating my Q, because I think I have writed wrong the code of input

Comment: The text description or the link; or both?